# Error build website using msbuild - ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, msbuild

I am attempting to build our web project using msbuild.exe under .NET 4.0.30319 when I get the following error:

ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This project has been building fine until about a month ago when we attempted to build after a long period of inactivity. I have tried the following:

1. Clearing the temporary ASP .NET Files areas under Framework and Framework64
2. Deleting all *.compiled files that may be pulled in
3. Rebuilding the web deployment project per [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1006055.aspx?Error%20on%20WDP%20build%20ASPNETCOMPILER%20error%20ASPRUNTIME%20Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object%20) post

All of those solutions seem to fail in this case. The strange thing to me is that when I inspect the logs and run the aspnet_compiler standalone (not through msbuild) I do not get the error, the ASPs compile to the designated deployment just fine.

Any suggestions for further steps to take would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue when the project was stored in dropbox folder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is Dropbox folder. We moved the project outside the Dropbox and everything worked ok